# How to copy from host machines to control machine using Ad-hoc command?

Tags: ansible

Previously, I ran a shell-script from control host and redirected all contents to output files. So, those files are in host provided directory.

Then I wanted to copy all the files from hosts to control host.
Is there anyway to do that?

For Ansible ad-hoc command to copy, as far as I know is something like

```
ansible all -m copy -a "src=..... dest=....."
```

I'm not sure if this also can bring back from host to control host?

Comment: An option would be to use [slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html#slurp-slurps-a-file-from-remote-nodes), or [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html#synchronize-a-wrapper-around-rsync-to-make-common-tasks-in-your-playbooks-quick-and-easy). But, let me ask you. Why not *scp*, or *rsync* when command-line is used?

Comment: you can use fetch module

Answer (score 1):

use: fetch modeule

Example from documentation

```
# Store file into /tmp/fetched/host.example.com/tmp/somefile
- fetch:
    src: /tmp/somefile
    dest: /tmp/fetched
```

Comment: Thanks for all comments!
I end up with create playbook and use fetch module.